# How to refresh treelist layout?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a `treelist` defined like so:

```
{
    xtype: "treelist",
    itemId: "MainMenu",
    store: {
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                 text: "One",
                 leaf: true,
                 iconCls: "x-fa fa-frown-o"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

When I load  a page, I see that this treelist is rendered ok. Then I click on a button, which executes this code:

```
mainmenu.getStore().add({
    text: "Two",
    leaf: true,
    iconCls: "x-fa fa-frown-o"
});
console.log(mainmenu.getStore().getCount()); // prints out correct value 2
```

The problem is that I still see only one item in the `treelist`. In other words, the `treelist` store is populated with new data, but does not show it. So, how can I fix it? I guess there should be some kind of refresh or update method, that will refresh the tree view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably using the TreeStore incorrectly. A tree store has one root and the children of that root get displayed by the TreeList recursively. To actually add to the tree store, however, you should use [NodeInterface](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.NodeInterface.html).

In your case:

```
mainmenu.getStore().getRootNode().appendChild({
    text: "Two",
    leaf: true,
    iconCls: "x-fa fa-frown-o"
});
```